# javascript extract email text-parts before and after

Tags: javascript, string, email, extract

I need to extract an email from a string.
The desired output is an array containing the text part before the email,
the email,
and the text after the email.

```
selection = 'Integer lectus nisi, facilisis sit amet@blabla.test eleifend nec, pharetra ut augue.';

part[0] = 'Integer lectus nisi, facilisis sit ';
part[1] = 'amet@blabla.test';
part[2] = ' eleifend nec, pharetra ut augue.';
```

What i have so far is a function extracting the email but i also need the parts before and after.

```
function extractEmails(selection){
     return selection.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi);
};

$output = extractEmails(selection); //returns 'amet@blabla.test'
```

How can this be done? Thanks!

Comment: I have a function that extracts the email. But i also need to have the parts before and after. function extractEmails(selection){
  return selection.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi);
};

Comment: Thanks! You need to add that to your question, so that we can see what you're doing; click on the [edit] link (either the one here or the one below the tags to your question) so that the code can be properly formatted. Show the function, show how you're calling it, explain the problems you've had, or are having, with it; explain what it does that it shouldn't do, and what it doesn't do that it should. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code might help you:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function extractEmails(selection){
        return selection.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi);
    };

    function parse(){
       var input = document.getElementById("input").innerText;
       var email = extractEmails(input);
       var subject = input.substring(0, input.indexOf(email));
       var content = input.substring(input.indexOf(email) + email.toString().length);

       // Print out parts
       var output = document.getElementById("output");
       output.innerText = `Subject: ${subject}\nEmail: ${email}\nContent: ${content}`;
    }
</script>
</head>

<body onLoad="parse()">
    Input: 
    <div id="input">Integer lectus nisi, facilisis sit amet@blabla.test eleifend nec, pharetra ut augue.</div>

    <hr/>
    Output: 
    <div id="output"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way,

```
var selection = 'Integer lectus nisi, facilisis sit amet@blabla.test eleifend nec, pharetra ut augue.';

var email = selection.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi)[0];

//console.log(email);

var desiredElement = selection.split(email);

Array.prototype.insert = function (index, item) {
  this.splice(index, 0, item);
};

desiredElement.insert(1, email);
console.log(desiredElement);
```

js fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/6gg93ff6/5/

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function is_email(email)
{
    var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}

var selection = 'Integer lectus nisi, facilisis sit amet@blabla.test eleifend nec, pharetra ut augue.';
var before = new Array();
var email = "";
var after = new Array();

var email_found = false;
var selection_parts = selection.split(" ");
for (var i = 0 ; i < selection_parts.length ; i++)
{
  if (is_email(selection_parts[i]))
  {
    email = selection_parts[i]
    email_found = true;
  }
  else
  {
    if(email_found) after.push(selection_parts[i]);
    else before.push(selection_parts[i]);
  }
}
final_array = [before.join(" "), email, after.join(" ")]
console.log(final_array);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers and suggestions!

i could work it out with:

```
 function extractEmails(string){
        return string.split(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi);
    };

    function parse(string){
        var i;
        var array = extractEmails(string);
        var myAssociativeArr = [];

        for (i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
            var newElement = {};
            if(array[i].match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi)){
                newElement['email'] = '[email_image,string=' + array[i] + ',id=2]';
            }else{
                newElement['text'] = array[i];
            }
            myAssociativeArr.push(newElement);
        }
        console.log(myAssociativeArr);
    }

    var string = 'Integer lectus nisi, facilisis sit email1@blabla.test eleifend nec, pharetra ut augue Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse email2@blabla.test cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.';
    parse(string);
```

Output:

```
[Object { text="Integer lectus nisi, facilisis sit "}, 
Object { email="[email_image,string=email1@blabla.test,id=2]"}, 
Object { text=" eleifend nec, pharetra ...n voluptate velit esse "}, 
Object { email="[email_image,string=email2@blabla.test,id=2]"}, 
Object { text=" cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur."}]
```